# Passing a DataTable object in Javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have in an *.aspx page, a call to a javascript function (defined elsewhere) that takes in an `object` as as parameter...

*myPage.aspx*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    BuildTable("Results/TableList/", "TableTitle",  {<%: Model.DataTable%>});
    refreshTable(sortTable["tbl-div_id"]);
</script>
```

*scripts.js*

```
//global
var sortTable = {};

function BuildTable(url, title, args)
{
   var myTable = new Object();
   myTable.postBackUrl = url;
   myTable.Title = title;
   myTable.args = (args != undefined) ? args : new Object();
   sortTable[<index>] = myTable;
 }

 function sortTable(selectedTable)
 {
    $.ajax({
        url: selectedtable.postBackUrl,
        data: selectedtable.args,
        sucess: function.....
        });
  }
```

*postBackUrl - in Controller*

```
[Authorize]
 public ActionResult TableList,<params>, DataTable values)
 {
     ...
     //`values` comes back a new object, there are no colmns defined, 
 }
```

I can see in `myPage.aspx` there are columns and rows defined for `<%:Model.DataTable%>` but as soon I go into javascript debuger, i can't recognize the object.

**QUESTION**

How Can I make sure the aspx page sends the entire DataTable object to the javascript and the javascript back to the server Controller so that I can then manipulate values?

**UPDATE**

If there's a way to go directly to the controller from the View, I'm open to that too

Comment: shouldn't this `<:` actually be this `<%Model.DataTable%>`

Comment: see edit.... still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Session[] variable.

*myPage.aspx*

```
 <%
    Session["myTable"] = Model.DataTable;
 %>
```

*postBackUrl - in Controller*

```
 DataTable table = (DataTable)HttpContext.Session["myTable"];
```

at this point, table now has the value of the Model and i din't have to deal with a complex data object in javascript

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a Typo on `<%:Model.DataTable%>` this should be  `<%=Model.DataTable%>` see if that helps otherwise what you can do is put that object as an hidden element in may be an input tag with an ID and pass that element object by the help of javascript `document.getElementById(id of your hidden Input)` see if that helps.

Comment: what are <%: %> and <%= %> called?  I would like to learn more about them... also, that did not work, I'm still not seeing anything come through in the javascript

Comment: Those are called  A scriptlet; it is a fragment of Java code that is run when the user requests the page. If this hasn't work I would give it a try with second option having a hidden table and getting a reference of that element by javascript `getElementById(id of the element);`

Comment: I ultimately want that object to be sent from javascript to the controller but javascript is typeless no? so won't that cause me to loose all the members of the object?

Comment: `getElementById(id of the element);` should be fine to get all the members of the table.

Comment: I'm not trying to use a value from HTML, there's no ID associated with the element, I'm trying to grab a member of the model

Comment: what comes when you log `<%=Model.DataTable%>` ? see if you actually have an element coming there?

Comment: it's nothing recognizable, it looks like a generic object but nothing is defined